# Upload functionality doesn't work on Some Devices

Tags: eclipse, android-camera, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload image and videos taken from mobile camera. For this I referred to the demo shown in [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/). The code works fine for many devices. But for some devices like Nexus 5, One+ one the video or image from the camera couldn't be uploaded. The operation is cancelled even before the API is called.

The problem is like, after the image or video is taken and the OK button is clicked there is no response. The Video Upload API is not called once the ok button is clicked.
Can anyone help me what the problem is??????

Comment: Even I couldn't get any Log for this.

Comment: Have you got any solution for your problem

Comment: Yes I used a hack here, for me intent came as null in onActivityResult, therefore in this scenario if the intent is null, just neglect it.